# Interceptor not executed when I refresh my page using "browser refresh/reload" or F5

Tags: angular, spring-security, angular7, jwt

I am currently learning angular 7 but I am facing and issue and would like your help to understand what is going on.
I am using JWT Authentication(Spring Boot Security) and on  each click my interceptor is called to set the token  before the request is sent to the server.
When I use browser back/forward, everything is working fine.
But if click on "browser refresh" , the interceptor is not not call and I am getting a Whitelabel Error Page.
My questions are :
1- why refresh is not not calling my interceptor?
2- Do you know how this can be solved?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpErrorResponse, 
HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenStorage } from './public/portal/token.storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

 const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';
@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private token: TokenStorage, private router: Router) {
}
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
let authReq = req;
if (this.token.getToken() != null) {authReq = req.clone({ 
    headers:req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + 
    this.token.getToken()) });
}
return next.handle(authReq).do(
  (err: any) => {

    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (err.status === 401) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    }
    console.log(err.status);
  }
);
}
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: The only reason I would expect an interceptor not to run on refresh is if the page you are loading does not initiate any HTTP calls. Refreshes will, however, destroy service variables -- how is your token stored? What is `this.token.getToken()` during a BACK and during a REFRESH -- do they differ? A `debugger` would be useful above the `return next.handle....`.

Comment: to save the token  I am using window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY,  token); During back and refresh, the token still there. They do not differ.

Comment: what do mean with "the page you are loading does not initiate any HTTP"?

Comment: any help guys? still not undertsand why my interceptor is not called after a browser reload

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Has anyone had any solution to this?

Comment: got the same issue :( any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it out. If you want the httpinterceptor to trigger after a reload your route needs to have a canactivate guard.

```
  {
    path: "members/edit", component: MembersEditComponent, canActivate: [AutoLoginAllRoutesGuard],
  },
  {
    path: "members/edit/:id", component: MembersEditComponent, canActivate: [AutoLoginAllRoutesGuard],
  },
```

Without the canActivate the interceptor does not seem to trigger when hitting F5.